# Where does my friend live? 3

Tags: knowledge, geography, history

<sup>*Other questions in this series can be found [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A71693+%22Where+does+my+friend+live%3F%22+is%3Aq).*</sup>

---

One of my friends in America has sent me some codes to show where he lives.

> ROY, LYS, INI, RAC, NIL, ROE, RAM, YES, CIT, DOH, SAM, IHS

**Can you figure out where in America he is?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most of this was worked out by Deepthinker101:

This is from

> The original 13 colonies, each of the three letters is a backwards portion of each of the colonies: New York, Pennsylvania, Virginia, North Carolina, South Carolina, Georgia, Maryland, New Jersey, Connecticut, Rhode Island, Massachusetts, New Hampshire in that order

Your friend lives in

> Delaware since it is the only one of the first 13 colonies that isn't listed

As for the people who downvoted, please understand that I had every intention to include @Deepthinker101's name in my answer, just forgot. And also, I created my own answer because Deepthinker had (what I thought) some inconsistent logic, even though he had the bulk of it. He also *had the checkmark* meaning I didn't think the checkmark would swap to me! Please understand what went on out here, please do not downvote because of that, again, I didn't mean to steal the thunder, just wanted to create my own storm using some of Deepthinker's low pressure system.

If you upvote this answer, upvote Deepthinker's too, I *almost definitely* couldn't have done it without 'em

Answer (score 12):

This is based on:

> 13 Colonies

In order the letters are disguising letters found in the 13 colonies:

> New York, Pennsylvania, Virginia, North Carolina, South Carolina, Maryland, Georgia, New Jersey, Connecticut, Rhode Island, Massachusetts, New Hampshire

So your friend is in the:

> Odd one out which is Delaware

Comment: I came on like 10 minutes ago too lol.

Comment: What about "CIT"?

Comment: @Deepthinker101 And why is Maryland the odd one out?